# Java IMAP connection error javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed

Tags: java, office365, jakarta-mail, imap

I am using below java program and configurations to read Inbox in outlook email, but could not succeed.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist;

import com.nexera.blustream.batch.constants.CommonConstants;
import com.nexera.blustream.batch.entity.SubscriberDetails;

public class EmailScanner {

    private String protocol;
    private String imapHost;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String folderName;
    private String excelFilePath;

    Properties prop;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(EmailScanner.class);

    public EmailScanner() {
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "config.properties";
            prop.load(EmailScanner.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream(propFileName));
            this.setProtocol(prop.getProperty("PROTOCOL"));
            this.setImapHost(prop.getProperty("IMAP_HOST"));
            this.setUsername(prop.getProperty("USERNAME"));
            this.setPassword(prop.getProperty("PASSWORD"));
            this.setFolderName(prop.getProperty("FOLDER_NAME"));
            this.setExcelFilePath(prop.getProperty("EXCEL_PATH"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * configureEmail() - used to connect to mailbox using properties mentioned
     * in config.properties.
     * passes the control to fetchUnReadMails.
     */
    public void configureEmail() {
        LOG.info("Entering method : configureEmail");
        // Download Attachment First
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", this.getProtocol());
        properties.setProperty("mail.imap.partialfetch", "false");
        properties.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");
        properties.put("mail.imap.tls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
        Folder inbox = null;
        Store store = null;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            LOG.info("Creating session for email with properties "
                    + properties.getProperty("mail.store.protocol"));

            session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
            store = session.getStore(this.getProtocol());
            LOG.info("Checking if store is connected " + store.isConnected());
            if (!store.isConnected()) {
                LOG.info("Store not connected, connecting");
                try {
                    store.connect(imapHost,993, username, password);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOG.error("Exception caught while connecting : "
                            + ex.getMessage());
                }

            } else {
                LOG.info("Store already connected, reading emails");
            }

            LOG.info("Reading emails");
            inbox = store.getFolder(folderName);
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            LOG.info("Opening Inbox in readWrite");
            fetchUnReadMails(inbox);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            LOG.error("Exception Thrown while reading mails :  " + e);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("Exception Thrown  while reading mails : " + ex);
        } finally {

            if (inbox != null) {
                if (inbox.isOpen())
                    try {
                        inbox.close(true);
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        LOG.error("Exception Thrown " + e.getMessage());
                    }
            }
            if (store != null) {
                if (store.isConnected())
                    try {
                        store.close();
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        LOG.error(
                                "Unable to close the store " + e.getMessage());
                    }
            }
        }
        LOG.info("Exiting method : configureEmail");
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("Starting Execution");
        EmailScanner emailBatchJob = new EmailScanner();
        emailBatchJob.configureEmail();
        LOG.info("Finished Execution");
    }
}
```

program is failing to connect to the server, exception is thrown at the below line

```
    store.connect(imapHost,993, username, password);
```

```
# MAIL BOX DETAILS FOR READING
PROTOCOL=imap
IMAP_HOST=outlook.office365.com
USERNAME=subscriptions@test.com
PASSWORD=<password>
FOLDER_NAME=Inbox`
```

#Exception Thrown

```
    javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:708)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:243)
    at com.email.demo.RetrieveEmailsUsingIMAP.getEmails(RetrieveEmailsUsingIMAP.java:46)
    at com.email.demo.RetrieveEmailsUsingIMAP.main(RetrieveEmailsUsingIMAP.java:241)
```

Your help is much appreciated!!!

Thanks

I have tried to change the protocol to imaps but didn't work.

Also, facing below error when I tried to do some other changes to the configurations

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection dropped by server?;
```

Comment: You need to configure your application to use XOAUTH2 authentication. Office 365 no longer supports "normal" authentication.

Comment: Hi @Mark Rotteveel, Thank you for your suggestion, could you please help me with some references how to configure/migrate normal authentication to XOAUTH2 authentication.